# VTK / ITK/ QT - unresolved external symbol error (LNK2001)

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, vtk, itk

On building my code with VTK 7.0 with Qt5.7 and and ITK 4.5 in Visual Studio 2013, I get the error below:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __cdecl vtkVRMLSource2::SetNthOutput(int,class vtkDataObject *)" (?SetNthOutput@vtkVRMLSource2@@MEAAXHPEAVvtkDataObject@@@Z)

The code corresponding to this file is this (`vtkVRMLSource2.cxx``):

```
#include "vtkVRML.h"
#include "vtkVRMLSource2.h"
#include "vtkVRMLImporter.h"
#include "vtkObjectFactory.h"
#include "vtkPolyData.h"
#include "vtkProperty.h"
#include "vtkActorCollection.h"
#include "vtkActor.h"
#include "vtkPointData.h"
#include "vtkCellData.h"
#include "vtkPolyDataMapper.h"
#include "vtkRenderer.h"
#include "vtkTransformPolyDataFilter.h"
#include "vtkAppendPolyData.h"
#include "vtkTransform.h"
#include "vtkUnsignedCharArray.h"
#include "vtkSmartPointer.h"
#include "vtkFloatArray.h"
#include "vtkDataObject.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
.....
idx = 0;
while ( (actor = actors->GetNextActor()) )
{
mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper::SafeDownCast(actor->GetMapper());
if (mapper)
  {
  //mapper->GetInput()->Update();
  //vtkPolyData *newOutput = vtkPolyData::New();
  vtkPolyData *newOutput = mapper->GetInput();
  //newOutput->CopyInformation(mapper->GetInput());
  this->SetNthOutput(idx, newOutput);
  ++idx;
  newOutput->Delete();
  newOutput = NULL;
  }
}
```

And the `vtkVRMLSource2.h` file is:

```
#include "vtkAlgorithm.h"
#include "vtkDataObject.h"
class vtkVRMLSource2 : public vtkAlgorithm{

public:
int  vtkTypeRevisionMacro(vtkVRMLSource2, vtkAlgorithm);
void PrintSelf(ostream& os, vtkIndent indent);
static vtkVRMLSource2 *New();
int NumberOfOutputs;

vtkSetStringMacro(FileName)
vtkGetStringMacro(FileName)

int GetNumberOfOutputs();
vtkPolyData* GetOutput(int idx);
vtkPolyData* GetOutput() { return this->GetOutput(0);}

vtkSetMacro(Color,int) // usage example: this->SetColor(1);
vtkGetMacro(Color,int)
vtkBooleanMacro(Color,int)

vtkSetMacro(Append,int) // usage example: this->SetAppend(1);
vtkGetMacro(Append,int)
vtkBooleanMacro(Append,int)

protected:
 vtkVRMLSource2();
 ~vtkVRMLSource2();

 void Execute();
 void InitializeImporter();
 void CopyImporterToOutputs();

 char* FileName;
 vtkVRMLImporter *Importer;
 int Color;
 int Append;

 virtual void SetNthOutput(int num, vtkDataObject *output);
 private:
   vtkVRMLSource2(const vtkVRMLSource2&);  
   void operator=(const vtkVRMLSource2&); 
};
```

I have linked all the proper VTK, ITK and Qt libraries in VS.
Could you please help me?

Comment: According to [this](https://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=VTK_6.0_Upgrade), you need to change `this->SetNthOutput(idx, newOutput)` to `this->GetExecutive()->SetOutputData(idx, newOutput)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide definition for `void SetNthOutput(int num, vtkDataObject *output)` which you declared in your header file. You could do it by adding this to vtkVRMLSource2.cxx:

```
void vtkVRMLSource2::SetNthOutput(int num, vtkDataObject *output)
{
    //code goes here
}
```